# rails relationship using unique key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, unique-key

Table/Entity 1: RetrievedDataRecords

Columns:

id

record_key

Table/Entity 2: SourceKeys

Columns:

id

key_name (unique key)

I cant alter these tables for legacy reasons, but want rails relationship between RetrievedDataRecord and SourceKey using record_key and key_name (they are the same key)

in RetrievedDataRecord, I tried something like:

belongs_to :source_key, :foreign_key => :record_key

but this doesn't work. I need some way to tell rails that record_key on this table is the same as key_name on the other table....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify also the `primary_key`:

```
belongs_to :source_key, :primary_key => :key_name, :foreign_key => :record_key
```

It should work!